# how to toggle a specific div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

i have dynamic data in my rails view, all divs have the same name; 'allData', which has alot of info, so i have it not displayed, i want to display that specific div and not all divs when i click show, but it shows all divs, i want to be able to show just that target div i clicked

```js
  $('.show'').on('click', (event) =>{ 
        $('.allData').toggle();
        $(event.currentTarget).closest('.allData').toggle(); 
    })
```

```html
<div class='eachData'>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='show'> show</div>
    <div class='numberOfdata'> 100</div>
  </div>  
  <div class='allData; display:none'>
    "foobar all data is here"
  </div>
</div>
<div class='eachData'>
  .......
</div>
<div class='eachData'>
  .......
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `closest` call is on the right track but you're not quite using it right. First you want to find the container (`.eachData`) that contains your `<div class="show">`, you use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for that:

```
let container = $(event.currentTarget).closest('.eachData');
```

then you search within that `container` for the `.allData` you want to toggle by using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
container.find('.allData').toggle();
```

So you use `closest` to go up the node tree and then `find` to come back down.

---

BTW, this:

```
<div class='allData; display:none'>
```

should be:

```
<div class="allData" style="display: none">
```

The `class` attribute contains CSS class names delimited by whitespace, raw CSS goes in the `style` attribute and is delimited by semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Your inline style on the div should be as follows:

```
<div class="allData" style="display: none">
```

Then try the following:

```
$('.show').on('click', function() {
    $(document).find('.eachData .allData:visible').hide('fast');
    $(this).parent().closest('.allData').show('fast');
});
```